# Flyway Migrations have failed validation error only in H2 file mode

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2, flyway

I was trying to run H2 file mode in Spring-boot with Flyway

I can see below error at the application start-up.

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.exception.FlywayValidateException: Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation
Detected failed migration to version 22.3.0.0 (create initial tables).
Please remove any half-completed changes then run repair to fix the schema history.
Need more flexibility with validation rules? Learn more: https://rd.gt/3AbJUZE
```

To my knowledge this can happen due to migration scripts errors. However same migration scripts works when I use H2 im memory mode. So that prroves nothing wrong with migration scripts.

**H2 File base properties**

```
spring:
  cache:
    enabled: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:./data/myDB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE  
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    baseline-on-migrate: true
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

  flyway:
    enabled: true
    username: sa
    password: sa  
    url: jdbc:h2:./data/myDB 
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    locations: filesystem:C:\myApi\api\src\integrationTest\resources\db.h2.migration
```

**H2 in-memory properties**

```
spring:
  cache:
    enabled: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1  
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    baseline-on-migrate: true
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

  flyway:
    enabled: true
    username: sa
    password: sa  
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDB 
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    locations: filesystem:C:\myApi\api\src\integrationTest\resources\db.h2.migration
```

What else could happen here?

**Versions:**

```
Spring Boot v2.7.8, Spring v5.3.25
"flyway", "7.2.1"
"h2", "2.1.214"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the in-memory database Flyway starts with an empty database. All scripts run without errors then.

On the other hand in a file version there is already the history of changes. Flyway has own tables to maintain the status of previous migrations. Apparently one of them was not successful and marked in the table as half-completed. It is the one with version 22.3.0.0

Solution 1

Initialize the database to be empty. Rerun the Flyway migrations from the beginning.

Solution 2

Manually change in the database the status of the broken migration. Rerun the Flyway starting with this one.

EDIT: From your comment I can see that the error still occurs even when database is empty. This means your settings are wrong for the scenario. In application.properties please change following:

Remove this properties:

```
spring.datasource.baseline-on-migrate
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization
spring.flyway.url
spring.flyway.username
spring.flyway.password
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate
```

Set this:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

The reason for the above settings is that Flyway should use the same datasource as Spring and not trying to create a different one. And it also should refrain from creating the tables from the entities.

Don't use data.sql to insert your test data to the database. It can not be mixed with Flyway migrations. Instead move your data.sql script to the directory with migrations and rename it to begin with V_23_0_xxx. This way it will be executed after the last migration which is V_22_3_xxx

I hope it helps. Otherwise please share the full log during application startup. Not only the few lines.

Comment: I manually deleted `/data/myDB` and re-ran the app, but same result. Further I added `spring.datasource.initialize: true`

Comment: How can I execute `data.sql` after FlywayMigration to load the data?